# how to remove default selected option color in react js

Tags: reactjs, select, select-options

I tried other solutions which I have searched in the internet but none of them were useful for me. My code is like this. for example I have tried this option: (provided, state) => ({
...provided,
backgroundColor: state.isSelected ? "rgba(189,197,209,.3)" : "white",
}), but it did not work